# EF Core, Class with Enum Column Definition

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, enums, .net-core

Today I started working on .Net Core (I want to port a current application I have), and I reached a point where I want to have a "Model" that has a basic structure (IQuery, it was an interface before) and well an Enum to define the Type.

So we have the Enum and the Abstract class (or interface, cant decide). The main point is the QueryType. Which on the derived classes it will be set by default into a specific Enum.

The problem is I get the following error:

> fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware[0]
>         An unhandled exception has occurred: The corresponding CLR type for entity type 'IQuery' is not instantiable and there is no derived entity type in the model that corresponds to a concrete CLR type.

Its been a long time since I wrote for ASPNET and damn it has changed.

Main abstract class + Enum

```
public enum QueryType
{
    MySQL = 0,
    MSSQL = 1,
    RabbitMQ = 2
};

public abstract class IQuery
{
    public IQuery() {}

    [Required]
    public string Id { get; set; }

     public QueryType QueryType { get; set; }

}
```

Extend Class

```
public class MySQL : IQuery
{
    public string Context { get; set; }

    new public QueryType QueryType
    { get; set; }
}
```